# Node js change url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm new to node.js and have been trying to find how to make it so in the url will be written 
localhost:8080/someText. while someText is the page I want to display.
If you could give me some tutorials how to do this, and also how to use and Id, for example: localhost:8080/someText=3

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a fairly popular NodeJS framework. Here is their Hello World example:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

})
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using express but didnt understand quite well.I'll try  again. And if you can reffer me to an example which routes you to a different directory then localhost:8080 as i wrote in the question?

Comment: Yeah, change `app.get('/', function (req, res) {` to `app.get('/myFolder', function (req, res) {`. See [this](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.METHOD) for routing and [this](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) for templating (e.g. handlebars, jade, ..).